# MySql not running; Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

Following error.

```
systemctl status mysql.service● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server  

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en  
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-07-05 23:1  
  Process: 26691 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
  Process: 26687 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi  
 Main PID: 26691 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 26692 (mysql-systemd  
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service  
           └─control  
             ├─26692 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post  
             └─26735 sleep 1  

Jul 05 23:19:16 g4080 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...  
Jul 05 23:19:16 g4080 mysqld[26691]: mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preced  
Jul 05 23:19:16 g4080 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exite  
lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

My Configuration File as asked, Pls suggest what should be the configuration, I am a newbie in mySql installation

GNU nano 2.5.3                                 File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

to one of:

```
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/default_storage_engine = innodb

innodb_file_per_table = 1

innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

Comment: From what i saw in other similar posts, there's a problem with your my.cnf, can you post it?

Comment: Hi Added the my.cnf file. Please suggest.

Comment: Indent the code in order be showed properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Did the (truncated) line "Found option without preced" originally read something like

```
Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line: 123
```

If that's the case, there's probably a option in your `my.cnf` file that's not assigned to a group. The `my.cnf` file is divided into several groups, one with options for the MySQL server, one with options for (command line) client, one with options for `mysqldump` and so on. If an option is outside of any such group, MySQL doesn't know what to apply it to.

If there's no "unattributed" option in your config, but MySQL still complains about one, you might want to look at [the file's encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020297/mysql-my-cnf-file-found-option-without-preceding-group#8020319).